# Best way to read and write two files?

Tags: python, xml, csv, scripting, elementtree

Folks, looking to get the suggestions on the best way to deal with the following task: 
1. Read data off of a CSV file. 
2. Edit an XML file based on the data read in Step 1.

I am a Python noob. So far I am able to read the data off of a CSV file. In my Java world, I would simply pass the "read" data off to a method and iterate over and edit the XML file in that method.
Can I do something similar in Python? Is there a more efficient and cleaner way of achieving the same in Python?

```
import csv

ifile  = open('my-file.csv', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)

rownum = 0
for row in reader:
    #print row
    if rownum == 0:
        header = row
    else:
        colnum = 0
        name = row[1]
        desig = row[5]
        print("Name: ", name)
        print("Designation: ", desig)


    rownum += 1
    if rownum == 10:
        break

ifile.close()
```

Comment: What is your problem in your code?

Comment: There's no issue with the code posted above. All I am asking is about how to define a method and pass arguments? and if it's the right approach.

Comment: "All I am asking is about how to define a method and pass arguments".  Seriously?  Read a tutorial.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I apologize, what I mean is if it's the right approach to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very similar to your solution, just uses `enumerate` and `with` instead of `open` and `close`:

```
import csv

with open('my-file.csv', 'rb') as ifile:
    reader = csv.reader(ifile)
    for rownum, row in enumerate(reader):
        #print row
        if rownum == 0:
            header = row
        else:
            colnum = 0
            name = row[1]
            desig = row[5]
            print("Name: ", name)
            print("Designation: ", desig)
        if rownum == 10:
            break
```

Comment: what's the benefit of using enumerate and with over open and close?

Comment: `enumerate` is a built-in function that saves you having to declare an index counter and increment it. `with` is useful because you don't have to worry about closing your file - in the case of an error when the program doesn't run to your `file.close()` the file will still close.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is missing a little bit of clarity (what is it that you are seeking).
Anyway, from what I understood, you are looking for an easy way to read a ***csv*** file and and print the ***ith*** columns in a certain formatting (e.g. name: ... ). 
I am assuming that your file looks like the following:

```
blah,Name,blahblah,blahblahblah,blahblahblahblah,Designation
whatever,name1,whatever,whatever,whatever,Designation1
whatever,name2,whatever,whatever,whatever,Designation2
whatever,name3,whatever,whatever,whatever,Designation3
whatever,name4,whatever,whatever,whatever,Designation4
whatever,name5,whatever,whatever,whatever,Designation5
whatever,name6,whatever,whatever,whatever,Designation6
```

If that is the case, then here is what I would do. I would use the known pandas library

```
import pandas as pd
```

Read the csv file into a dataframe "df"

```
df = pd.read_csv('my-file.csv')
```

The variable header will hold the column names

```
header = list(df) # the equivilant of your "row[0]" variable
```

Method #1 of printing the required data

```
for i, j in zip(list(df['Name'].values), list(df['Designation'].values)):
    print "Name: {} \nDesignation: {}".format(i, j)
```

This prints out the following:

```
Name: name1 
Designation: Designation1
Name: name2 
Designation: Designation2
Name: name3 
Designation: Designation3
Name: name4 
Designation: Designation4
Name: name5 
Designation: Designation5
Name: name6 
Designation: Designation6
```

Method #2 of printing the required data

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].map('Name: {}'.format)
df['Designation'] = df['Designation'].map('Designation: {}'.format)
print df[['Name', 'Designation']].head(n=10)
```

Which will print out the following:

```
0  Name: name1  Designation: Designation1
1  Name: name2  Designation: Designation2
2  Name: name3  Designation: Designation3
3  Name: name4  Designation: Designation4
4  Name: name5  Designation: Designation5
5  Name: name6  Designation: Designation6
```